# Cannot get consent to connect SPFX webpart with Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying to connect to Azure Devops from within a Sharepoint web part.

I have added a couple of permission requests in package-solution.json:

```json
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
    {
      "resource": "Windows Azure Active Directory",
      "scope": "User.Read"
    },
    {
      "resource": "Azure DevOps",
      "scope": "user_impersonation"
    },
    {
      "resource": "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal",
      "scope": "user_impersonation"
    }
    ...
```

and use the AAD factory to call an Azure DevOps api, like so:

```js
this.context.aadHttpClientFactory.getClient('499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798').then((client: AadHttpClient) => {      
  client.get(`https://dev.azure.com/reinder0498/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0`, AadHttpClient.configurations.v1)
  .then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
  })
  .then((projects: any): void => {
      console.log(projects);
  });
});
```

But then I get this error: "The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '177c71fc-1022-4e3c-82cd-faa17d9864bf' named 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource."

I've looked at pending and approved requests in Sharepoint Admin center but could not see any requests coming in...
What else do I have to do to use the aadHttpClientFactory to connect to Azure DevOps API's?

[image]

**update**

If I browse to that Sharepoint Online Client app in AAD, the button to grant admin consent is disabled:

[image]

Comment: Could you check the following documentation to see whether it helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I have seen it, but that is about enterprise API's and I want to connect to Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure it out myself. The thing is that you need to run it inside your teams environment to have the approval request created in your Sharepoint environment.

I now have these permission requests configured:

```json
{
   "resource": "Azure DevOps",
   "scope": "user_impersonation"
},
{
   "resource": "Windows Azure Active Directory",
   "scope": "User.Read"
}
```

I uploaded my web part to Sharepoint, synced it to Teams and then opened it inside Teams. At some point I got the error message about the consent and then afterwards I saw the approval request appear in Sharepoint Admin.

Once approved, my web part successfully connected to the DevOps REST API.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs for the application registered with Azure AD (Delegated Permissions), which requires either user or an administrator’s consent for the permissions it needs.
You need configure permissions in the azure portal for your application and or create a url and grant permissions first . Below is link on how too construct the url. You only need to do it once and can remove permissions when needed.

Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent

Also, here is a GitHub issue raised and solved regarding your setup.
[SPFX USER](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2473#:%7E:text=-%20Click%20%22View%20all%20applications%22%20-%20Click%20%22SharePoint,%22API%20Managment%22-section:%20-%20Ensure%20that%20%22Windows%20Azure)

Comment: OK, so I tried to configure permissions for Sharepoint SPFX (if that's the one I need, not really clear), using its Application ID in the URL provied, and then I get a 'Permissions requested' dialog but when I click 'Accept', I get an error: 'Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.'

Comment: Are you an admin or authorized user? Login into azure portal and make sure you are added for that application -sp . Also maybe logout of everything and try with fresh cleared cache. Could be just be login issuers . Also , does it ask if you grant permission for on behalf of organization?

Comment: I am an admin indeed, but it's a trial version of Sharepoint. I'm not sure which app to grant permissions; I can see a 'sharepoint spfx' application and I can click the 'Grant admin consent' button and follow the next steps succesfully, but I still get the error as above. How do i grant application 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal' access as well?

Comment: Hmm... can you find the user group in azure portal ? Also are you building from TFS and the service account  from tfs azure trying to talk to the application on SharePoint ? Hmm any way you try from build account ?

Comment: I'm just trying out a webpart, running it in Sharepoint workbench (https://[site].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx)

Comment: Thought was devops api. Eitherway let me get back too you. Was the msft document helpful?

Comment: constructing that `adminconsent` url was'nt working for me ('having trouble with signing you in') but I am able to grant permissions for each enterprise application. I'm just not sure which application to grant permissions for... I tried 'sharepoint spfx' but that didn't help. I was hoping to see a 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal' application in my enterprise applications but I can't find it...

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way :)
I'm trying to get this piece of code to work for me: https://github.com/kmprasad4u/SPFx-DevOps

Comment: Found this look at bottom...https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2473#:~:text=-%20Click%20%22View%20all%20applications%22%20-%20Click%20%22SharePoint,%22API%20Managment%22-section:%20-%20Ensure%20that%20%22Windows%20Azure

Comment: Not clear what I have to look at... bytheway, if I navigate to 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal' in Azure AD portal and go to 'Permissions', the button to grant admin consent is disabled (see updated post).